# How to update a column from another column in the same table in a list of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, qsqlquery

I have the following data structure in `Table A`:

```
RequestId  |  Serial  |  RowSerial
-----------+----------+----------
   1       |    1     |    NULL
   1       |    2     |    NULL
   1       |    3     |    NULL
```

I need a query to have the following update:

```
RequestId  |  Serial  |  RowSerial
-----------+----------+----------
   1       |    1     |    501
   1       |    2     |    502
   1       |    3     |    503
```

500 is a static number that is added to the `Serial` column and is set to `RowSerial` column.

I have tried this:

```
UPDATE Table A
SET RowSerial=(SELECT top 1 500+(Serial) FROM Table A where requestid=1 and RowSerial is Null) where requestid=1
```

But it didnt work. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple addition:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET RowSerial = 500 + Serial
WHERE RequestId = 1 AND RowSerial IS NULL
```

use the `WHERE` part only if you want to restrict the update to specific rows.

Answer (score 2):

Simply

```
UPDATE TableA
SET RowSerial = Serial + 500;
```